# query to search country name in text

Tags: sql, sqlite, match

I need a simple query that looks for a country in a text.
I have one table with different articles and on table with all the country names in the world.

> **ID    |   Article**
>
> 1     | In China a three headed squid was sold to a bike vendor
>
> 2     | The government of Nigeria organised a slumber party
>
> 3     | Austria to ban australian comedians
>
> **CID   | Name**
>
> 1     | Nigeria
>
> 2     | Niger
>
> 3     | Austria
>
> 4     | China*

I only need the matches where the full country name appears in the article. I am currently using a 'like' query :

```
> Where a.Article like '%'||b.Name||'%'
```

but this way the article from NIGERIA is also matched to NIGER.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE a.Article RLIKE "[[:<:]]b.Name[[:>:]]"
```

Try the above where clause

Here is a SQL fiddle, in which I select all the articles from the articles table, which are referring to Nigeria.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b8c6/3

Comment: I have to implement this query in a software package that only supports SQLite, so unfortunatly the RLIKE does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a blank before and after the country name like this:

```
Where a.Article like '% '||b.Name||' %'
```

Not quite correct as you need to consider also that the country name is the first and the last word. So you will need also to check

```
Where a.Article like '%'||b.Name||' %'
```

and

```
Where a.Article like '% '||b.Name||'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:!

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_article a WHERE (a.Article REGEXP ('EXACT VALUE'));
```

Comment: Or, REGEXP (tableb.Name);

Comment: Can you complete the where clause to make it match the country NAME table?

Comment: Use this `(REGEXP '[[:<:]]Niger[[:>:]]');`